# Text mining - feature with a lot of spelling probs and differentations

Tags: r, nlp, text-mining, knime

I'd like to make sense of the feature "color". The problem is that it has more than 15.000 specifications with a lot of spelling problems (e.g brwon <-> brown, oliv <-> olive), but also differentations (lightblue <-> blue) in it.

How is it possible to make sense of such a feature? Are there any resources, R packages or python modules?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

R can use aspell (command is available). But you need to install aspell on your machine and maybe even hunspell. Hunspell is used as a spellcheck in chrome / firefox and Rstudio for example.

Read this [journal](http://journal.r-project.org/archive/2011-2/RJournal_2011-2_Hornik+Murdoch.pdf) for more information about aspell and hunspell in R.

But this will only take care of spelling errors. You could use regex to look for main colors.